# Search Range Based on Partial Sting to Match Unknown Sheet Name

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, match, string-matching

I am trying to find text in MonthlyData which may be a partial match to a Sheet name.

I will not know the sheet names and I am making the assumption that users may type in partial names in the MonthlyData field.

```
Sub GetData()

Dim Data As Worksheet, WkSh As Worksheet
Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

Dim TITLE As Range, MktPlace As Range, NetUnitsSold As Range, MonthlyData As Range
Set MonthlyData = Data.Range("A1:M500")
Set TITLE = MonthlyData.Columns("A")
Set MktPlace = MonthlyData.Columns("D")
Set NetUnitsSold = MonthlyData.Columns("G")

With MonthlyData.Cells
    .Find(what:=WkSh.Name, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: A syntax error is generated after the .Find because of the parentheses. Also, WkSh is not assigned a value ... but I assume that this is because of the issue/challenge you have. Do I understand your challenge correctly by saying that the data in the cells is a partial match (e.g. "JUN") is to be matched to one or more worksheet names (e.g. "JUNE"), then if so, you may need to create a loop though the cells and an inner loop across worksheet names(?). Maybe if you had some example data a more targeted suggestion could be made.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a for loop. Here is one idea:

```
dim r as range
dim result as string

for each r in monthlycells
    if lcase(wksh.name) like "*" & lcase(r.value2) & "*" then
        result = r.value2
    end if
next
```

Note: The [like operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) is case sensitive.

Comment: This is also giving me an error. Object Variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: You never set `WkSh` in the routine your provided. That may be it.

Comment: I figured, but I'm not sure how to set it when the name is unknown.